# send email using Google's GmailAPI

Tags: android, gmail, google-play-services, gmail-api

i am trying to use gmail API for sending email and find good example at https://github.com/skadyrov/GmailAPI-android-example here he use to and from email id for sending email in GmailUtil.java file. but it is always sending email from selected account.is this is default behavior that email is sent always from choosen account?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the FROM address to any email address that is set as an alias in your Gmail account.

```
private static final String FROM = "<your email alias>";
```

Comment: @ Amit Agarwal and if that account is not setup as gmail alias then email will be sent from selected account ?